# How to include bluez latest version library using CMake in project

Tags: linux, bluetooth, cmake, bluez

I want to include bluez latest version (5.44) to my C program project. I am using CMake for build purpose. I tried using `pkg_check_modules` as below

```
pkg_check_modules (BLUEZ REQUIRED bluez)
include_directories(${BLUEZ_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${BLUEZ_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

But It always finds the older version 5.37. How can I point this to take latest version ?

I already tried this as well but it throws the error as below.

```
pkg_check_modules (BLUEZ REQUIRED bluez=5.44)
include_directories(${BLUEZ_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${BLUEZ_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

Error getting :

```
Checking for module 'bluez=5.44'
--   
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:367 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:532 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:30 (pkg_check_modules)
```

I downloaded the latest bluez version and built and installed using `sudo make install`. I am able to find and use the `bluetoothctl` tool.

Comment: Do you have `.pc` file for manually installed bluez (5.44)? I don't see any one in the [source tree](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/). Utility `pkg-config` cannot find anything without such files.

Comment: @Tsyvarev `bluez.pc` is auto-generated by autotools. OP's `pkg-config` is most likely unaware of its install location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to make sure that `pkg-config` can find your installed version of `bluez`. If it can't, then CMake won't be able to either.

```
$ pkg-config --modversion bluez
```

If that does not give you the version you expect, then you need to find the `bluez.pc` for the version that you want, and make sure its directory is at the beginning of PKG_CONFIG_PATH. Since you stated that you used `sudo make install`, the `bluez.pc` you want is most likely at `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/bluez.pc`. (You will need to look yourself to be sure.) If that's the case, then

```
$ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH} pkg-config --modversion bluez
```

should return the the version your looking for. If so, do what's necessary to make that change permanent to your shell. Delete your CMake cache, and re-cmake your project.

Comment: I found the bluez.pc and changed the installation location and version accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While the question has a manually compiled `Bluez` version included in many cases people might run into the exact same issue after doing a standard installation of `Bluez` through `apt` on any Debian system.

However to do development in a project with Bluez one also has to install Bluez developement files. This can be done with

```
apt install libbluetooth-dev
```

which should in turn install the bluez.pc file in the standard location making both `pkg-config --modversion bluez` and any `pkg_check_modules (BLUEZ REQUIRED bluez)` resolve correctly.